# Uniswap Widget is now working with next.js 14

Tags: widget, next.js14, uniswap

anyone who has integerated uniswap with next.js 14. I'm using that with next.js 14 and if i use "use client" directive i get the following error

```
./node_modules/brotli/build/encode.js:2:141
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

if i don't use "use client" directive, i get the following error.

```
Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component
```

Any update on the swap widget. Here is my code for that

```
// 'use client';

import React from 'react';
import '@uniswap/widgets/fonts.css';
import { SwapWidget } from '@uniswap/widgets';

const Uniswap = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Uniswap">
      <SwapWidget />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Uniswap;
```

I want the uniswap widget to be working